# SQL - Converting Datepart to tinyint

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Declare @Date date = getdate()

select DATEpart(WEEKDAY,@Date)as day32    
SELECT CAST(@Date AS tinyint)

If  @Date !=7 and @Date!=1
```

I need help converting a `date` data type to a `tiny int`

This is the error message I get when I try to execute

> Explicit conversion from data type date to int is not allowed.

Comment: Which int value would you expect? The day's index in its year? The day's index in the week? Some "show me the int value of the binary which is a date"? Please explain...

Comment: I want to see a number value representing which day of the week it is eg. Sunday =1 Monday=2 Tuesday=3 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = GETDATE(),
        @TinyDate TinyInt

SELECT @TinyDate = CONVERT(TINYINT,DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date))
```

DATE can't be converted to INT so you have an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())
```

But please be aware of the influence of your system's culture. Some countries start their week on Monday other on Sunday...

You should read a bit about DATEFIRST-option

```
SELECT @@DATEFIRST --Your current setting
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using `CAST()` on the result of the `DATEPART()`, you're using `CAST()` on the variable which has a datatype of `DATE`, you can `CAST( AS TINYINT)` in the same line as the `DATEPART()`:

```
Declare @Date date = getdate()  
select CAST(DATEpart(WEEKDAY,@Date)AS TINYINT) as day32
```